# How to use relative urls in angular 1.5 across all modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

I'm using angular 1.5 and webpack to generate a *dist* folder with my angular aplication.

This is my folder structure:

```
--app
  --dist
    --loginComponent
      --login.html
    --homeComponent
      --home.html
    ...
    --app.css
    --app.js
  --index.html
```

And this is my index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es" ng-app="firmaDigitalApp" ng-strict-di>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/app.css">
<script src="dist/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <app></app>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything good so far, the problem is that app.js generated is not accessing the html by its path in a relative manner so it can't find the resource (instead of looking for home.html in *context*/dist/homeComponent.html, it's looking for it in *context*/homeComponent.html).

Just in case, this is homeModule.js:

```
require('./administradorComponent/administradorModule.js');
require('./definicionComponent/definicionModule.js');

var controller = require('./homeController');

var homeModule = angular.module('homeModule', [ 'administradorModule', 'definicionModule' ]);

homeModule.component('homeComponent',
{
  templateUrl : 'homeComponent/home.html',
  $routeConfig : [
    {
     path : '/administrador/...',
     name : 'Administrador',
     component : 'administradorComponent',
     useAsDefault : true
     }]
});

homeModule.controller('homeController', [ '$rootScope', '$location', '$log', controller ]);
```

What can I do so my angular application resources use relative paths to access each other so I don't have to type *dist/* over and over again?

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Are you using [Angular UI Router](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router) in your app?

Comment: No, but I am willing to if it will solve this problem.

Comment: Can you show me the code where you refer to the `templateUrl`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using `templateUrl`, I'd recommend using [`html-loader`](https://github.com/webpack/html-loader) to make your templates be built into your output file (i.e. `app.js`). If you set that up, you can just do:

```
template: require("homeComponent/home.html") // Resolves to a string
```

This will cause your bundle to take a little longer to download up front, as all the templates will get loaded too, but you won't have to wait for the templates to load asynchronously when the component is initialized, so it evens out in my opinion.